# How can I distribute points evenly along an oval?

Tags: svg, vector, graphics, geometry, shader

I have an oval (as an svg)

I want to distribute *n* points along the oval:

- evenly
- inset the points by *x* percent
- constrained to the lower *f* percent of the oval

How can I do this programmatically? I just need a list of coordinates as output.

[image]

SVG of an ellipse:

```
<svg id="svg2" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="297mm" width="210mm" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047">
 <g id="layer1">
  <ellipse id="path8074" rx="78.559" ry="105.84" stroke="#000" cy="489.51" cx="314.29" stroke-width=".38188px" fill="none"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: concerning the inset: `X` percent of what? And the inset is orthogonal to the ellipse's boundary? and concerning the constraint: `f` percent of what? And the end points shall have the same distance to the blue boundary as to the next neighbour point?

Answer (score 3):

Calculating equidistant point on ellipse circumference is quite complex math problem. Moreover, parallel curve (inward) for an ellipse is not ellipse.

If your ellipse is not very squeezed (a/b ratio is in range 0.5..2), you can use simple approximation through equidistantly spaced t parameter of ellipse equaion. Otherwise distance variance will too high and you need more complex approach based on arc length/distance calculation (requires numerical integration).

[Edit]: I added some correction of t to make point distribution better. Idea taken [from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172766/calculating-equidistant-points-around-an-ellipse-arc),

Using [parallel curve equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipseParallelCurves.html), we can calculate points in such way (Delphi code as reference):

```
var
  i, a, b, cx, cy, x, y, k, N: Integer;
  sq, t: Double;
begin
  N := 30;     // Number of points
  a := 120;  //semiaxes
  b := 200;
  cx := 300;   //center
  cy:= 300;
  k := 30;     //inward distance

  Canvas.Ellipse(cx - a, cy - b, cx + a, cy + b);
  for i := 0 to N - 1 do begin
    t := 2 * Pi * i / N;
    //empirically adopted coefficient 0.3
    t := t + 0.3 * ArcTan((a-b)*tan(t)/(a + b * sqr(tan(t))));
    sq := 1.0 / Hypot(a * sin(t), b * cos(t));
    x := Round(cx + (a - b * k * sq) * Cos(t));
    y := Round(cy + (b - a * k * sq) * Sin(t));
    Canvas.Ellipse(x-2,y-2,x+3,y+3);
  end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it:

1. I've changed the ellipse you have so that I center it around 0. To keep the position I translate the group `<g id="layer1" transform="translate(314.29,489.51)">`.
2. I draw another ellipse inside. The `rx` attribute of this ellipse is the `rx` of the `path8074` ellipse multiplied by a factor. Let's say .8. The same for the `ry`. I'm calling this ellipse `inner`
3. I calculate the total length of the inner ellipse using `let innerLength = inner.getTotalLength();`
4. `let n = 10`: this is the number of points you need to inset
5. I'm using a loop `for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){` to calculate the coords of the points on the inner path `let length = i * innerLength / n; let p = inner.getPointAtLength(length);`and to draw a circle to mark the point: `drawCircle({cx:p.x,cy:p.y,r:2}, layer1)`

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let rx = path8074.getAttribute("rx");
let ry = path8074.getAttribute("ry");

let factor = .8;
inner.setAttributeNS(null,"rx",rx*factor);
inner.setAttributeNS(null,"ry",ry*factor);

let innerLength = inner.getTotalLength();
let n = 10;//n points

for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
  let length = i * innerLength / n;
  let p = inner.getPointAtLength(length);
  drawCircle({cx:p.x,cy:p.y,r:2}, layer1)
}

// a function to draw a circle
function drawCircle(o, parent) {
  var circle = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(circle);
  return circle;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg2" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="297mm" width="210mm" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" viewBox="200 350 744.09448819 1052.3622047">
 <g id="layer1" transform="translate(314.29,489.51)">
  <ellipse id="path8074" rx="78.559" ry="105.84" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".38188px" fill="none"/>
  <ellipse id="inner" stroke="#000"  stroke-width=".38188px" fill="none"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

I hope it helps.

OBSERVATION: I've changed the viewBox of the svg element because I wanted the ellipses in view. You can change it back to what it was.